# To get a field from sqlite database using its corresponding column field

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database in sqlite for android with variables like Acc No, name, date etc etc.
i have many edit text in my activity. when the acc no is entered in Acc No edit text, the corresponding name should appear in below Name edit text. how to do that.

my DB code is given below

public  void getName(Editable account_edit_txt){

```
  "Acc_No " + account_edit_txt, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"Cust_Name","Acc_No"}, "Acc_No=?",new String[]{"account_edit_txt"}, null, null, null);
    Log.e("running", "cursor run");
    if(cursor!=null)
     {

         Log.e("running", "curosr is not null");
     while(cursor.isFirst())
     {

         Log.e("running", "cursor while loop enter");

         String temp =  (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Cust_Name")));
             String temp2 =(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Acc_No")));
        Log.e("running", "id acc num" +temp+ " name"+temp2);

    }
 }
```

Activity code is given below

public class TransactionActivity extends Activity {

```
EditText acc_edit;
TextView acc_txt;
Editable account_edit_txt;
Connection connection;
String name;
SQLiteDatabase sdb;

AccountDBAdapter db = new AccountDBAdapter(this);

//

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.transaction_page);

    acc_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_Acc_No);
    acc_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_show_name);
    final String editable = String.valueOf(acc_edit.getText());

    Log.e("editable value", "" + account_edit_txt);
    acc_edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

            if (start >= 2) {
                db.open();
                account_edit_txt = acc_edit.getText();
                db.getName(account_edit_txt);
                db.close();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function will help you to retrieve account holder name for given account number.
Non need to fecth Acc_No again. Ad you are already have account number which user has inserted.

Also assuming that there will be only one record associated with the give account number.

```
public String getAccountHolderName(String accountNumber) {
        String accountHolderName = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { "Cust_Name" },
                "Acc_No=?", new String[] { accountNumber }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            accountHolderName = (cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Cust_Name")));

            cursor.close();
        }

        return accountHolderName;
    }
```